# Laravel - Create dynamically prefixed database tables based on separate table row creation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-artisan

When I create a new "company" in the database, it gets an ID. Upon creation of that company, I want to dynamically create tables prefixed with this ID. For instance:

1. Company 01 created in table Companies.
2. Table 01_data_type created.
3. Table 01_other_data_type created.

Step 1 is triggered by form. Steps 2-3 and beyond are triggered by step 1.

The best way I can think to do this inside Laravel is in my store method, upon store, call an artisan command for the migration and pass the ID. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Better is subjective here, but I would argue that it should be a [model event](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#model-events) that spawns a Job that is responsible for it. If you need to be able to manually create them, then an artisan command makes sense, and the job can spawn the artisan command. If not, then the job alone is fine for handling the logic.

Comment: THIS is awesome. That makes total sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided by @Ohgodwhy in comments on question. spawn a job that creates the tables dynamically.